# Implausible date in RSS how to fix it in PHP?

Tags: php, rss

I have a RSS with:

```
<pubDate>Fri, 20 Apr 2012 08:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
```

And validator said it is not proper because:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/ImplausibleDate.html

"While this date-time value is formatted correctly, it either appears to be in the future, or far enough in the past to indicate that there might either be a software error, or an incorrectly set clock, involved.

While the RSS 2.0 spec anticipated that some aggregators may chose to ignore items with pubDates in the future, this practice never seemed to catch on.

Instead, many clients sort by dates, either by default, or as an option. For this reason, it is important that date values are as accurate as possible.

One common error, particularly among the British and Western Europe during the summer time (i.e., during the periods of BST and WEST), is for the numeric part of the time to reflect local time and for the zone part of the time to hard code GMT.
"

I generate the date with:

```
<pubDate>$data2 GMT</pubDate>
```

where $data2 is taken from database as folows:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%a, %d %b %Y %T')
```

And the DATE was received by mysql function NOW().

It's weird because here we have 9:24 o'clock but we had in Poland change of time lately. So how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your timezone instead of GMT:

```
<pubDate>$data2 +0200</pubDate>
```

That should do it. Note that your timezone might change over the year, so you might want to dynamically [generate](http://php.net/date) it:

```
$data2 .= date(' O');
```

Comment: I'm running WordPress in 5.7 and found that this solution was implemented by setting `$date = get_lastpostmodified( 'blog' );` per the doc found [Inline Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_lastpostdate/#parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Format is all right. Standard time format for RSS 2.0 must be GMT, please format time to GMT, note it would not faster then current time.

```
$data2 = gmdate(DATE_RSS, time());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<pubDate><?php echo date(DATE_RFC822); ?></pubDate>
```

http://feed2.w3.org/docs/error/InvalidRFC2822Date.html

Edit: get the date as unix timestamp from the db and pass it as second parameter to the date() function.